# c++ writing data to file without duplicates

Tags: c++, file

I have created some methods which will write song data to a text file.
If the file doesn't exist it will create a new one.

The problem I am having is that every time I run the application again it will append to the file and duplicate all the data.

**This Method is called first**

```
void SongLibrary::SaveAllToFile(string fileName)
{
    for (Song song : m_songs)
    {
        WriteToFile(song.ToFileString(),fileName);
    }
}
```

**This method is called once for each song object**

```
void SongLibrary::WriteToFile(string data, string fileName)
{
    if (FileExists(fileName))
    {
        ofstream outfile;
        outfile.open(fileName, ios::app);
        outfile << data;

        outfile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        CreateFile(fileName);
        WriteToFile(data, fileName);
    }
}
```

**This method creates a file**

```
void SongLibrary::CreateFile(string fileName)
{
    ofstream outfile(fileName);
    outfile.close();
}
```

**This method checks if a file exists**

```
inline bool SongLibrary::FileExists(const string& fileName) 
{
    struct stat buffer;
    return (stat(fileName.c_str(), &buffer) == 0);
}
```

Comment: `ios::app` tells it to append. You need to keep the stream object around. Don't open the file every time you need to write something to it.

Comment: ok, I see what your saying. I should open the file outside the for loop and then append each song object to it yes?

Comment: Pretty much. I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the file once and write to the same stream object. Without the `ios::app` parameter it will truncate the file when it's opened for writing. Also, you don't need to `close()` a `std::ofstream` because it's closed automatically in its destructor.

```
void SongLibrary::SaveAllToFile(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ofstream outfile(filename);
    for(auto& song: m_songs)
        outfile << song.ToFileString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't open/close the file each time you're writing something in it, as you did in your `WriteToFile` function (in append mode)

Just create an `ofstream` object (part of std library) and pass it to your `WriteToFile` function like this.

```
void SongLibrary::SaveAllToFile(string fileName)
{
    ofstream outfile(filename);

    for (Song song : m_songs)
    {
        WriteToFile(song.ToFileString(),outfile);
    }

    outfile.close();
}
```

And change your `WriteToFile` function to handle this object :

```
void SongLibrary::WriteToFile(string data, ofstream& outfile)
{
        outfile << data;
}
```